# $K_1(\mathbb{Z})$ is covered by diagonal matrices with only $\pm 1$ entries

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let me give some definitions first:

- We define the inclusion $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})\to GL(n+1,\mathbb{Z})$ as $A\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$
- We call $E(n,\mathbb{Z})$ the subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ generated by elementary matrices (i.e. the ones with $1$ everywhere in the diagonal and a single entry $=1$ outside the diagonal)
- Define the direct limits $GL(\mathbb{Z}):=\lim_\limits{\to}GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ and $E(\mathbb{Z}):=\lim_\limits{\to}E(n,\mathbb{Z})$ with respect to the inclusion map written above.
- It can be proved that $E(\mathbb{Z})$ is a normal subgroup of $GL(\mathbb{Z})$ and we call $K_1(\mathbb{Z}):=GL(\mathbb{Z})/E(\mathbb{Z})$.

> My question is how can I show that the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}\pm 1&&&\\&\\&\pm1&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&\pm1\end{pmatrix}$ cover all classes in $K_1(\mathbb{Z})$?

In simpler terms: how can I get all invertible matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ by elementary row/column operation (up to enlarging the matrix and adding $1$'s in the right bottom corner)?

I know that $K_1(\mathbb{Z})$ is actually $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but I guess this particular fact can be shown directly and elementary.

Thank you!

Comment: By $K_1,$ do you mean that of algebraic $K-$theory?

Comment: yes sorry, I meant that one